# aws kernel is killing my node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, redis, database

Problem :

I am executing test of my mongoose query but kernel kills my node app for OutOfMemory Reasons.

flow scenario: for a single request

/GET REQUEST -> READ document of user(eg.schema) [This schema has ref : user schema with one of its fields] -> COMPILE/REARRANGE the output of query read from mongodb [This involves filtering and looping of data] according the response format as required by the client. -> UPDATE a field of this document and SAVE it back to mongoDB again -> UPDATE REDIS -> SEND response [the above compiled response ] back to requested client

** the above fails when 100 concurrent customers do the same...
MEM - goes very low (<10MB)
CPU - MAX (>98%)

What i could figure out is the rate at which read and writes are occurring which is choking mongodb by queuing all requests and thereby delaying nodejs which causes such drastic CPU and MEM values and finally app gets killed by the kernel.

PLEASE suggest how do i proceed to achieve concurrency in such flows...

Answer (score 0):

You've now met the [Linux OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).  Basically, all linux kernels (not just Amazon's) need to take action when they've run out of RAM, so they need to find a process to kill.  Generally, this is the process that has been asking for the most memory.

Your 3 main options are:

1. Add swap space.  You can create a swapfile on the root disk if it has enough space, or create a small EBS volume, attach it to the instance, and configure it as swap.
2. Move to an instance type with more RAM.
3. Decrease your memory usage on the instance, either by stopping/killing unused processes or reconfiguring your app.

Option 1 is probably the easiest for short-term debugging.  For production performance, you'd want to look at optimizing your app's memory usage or getting an instance with more RAM.

Comment: Do you think adding redis would suffice

Comment: As long as redis is not running on the same instance (otherwise it would just eat more memory that you don't have) and is configured correctly.  I can't really say for certain without knowing your app design, though.

Comment: Redis won't help if you're still trying to load more data into your application than the instance memory can hold, though.  A caching layer between your database and your application won't change that.